# Magento 1.9 attribute value doesn't show up in order confirmation

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, order-email

I'm trying to display a custom attribute value in the order confirmation email. Tried it with multiple codes and settings, but the only thing I can manage to show is NULL.

It's about a configurable product. The 'parent' product doesn't have the attribute 'leveranciersnummer' filled in. The child products do. Here's the configuration of my custom attribute:
https://ibb.co/GTwzG6p

In the order confirmation email template (default.phtml) (/template/email/order/items/order), I added:

`$leverancier = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId())->getLeveranciersnummer();`

But when I echo that, it just displays NULL. It's clearly filled in when I look into the edit product page of the product SKU from the order confirmation email. If I display a var_dump of the $_item->getProjectId, I get a bunch of information, but my custom attribute 'leveranciersnummer' isn't there.

I also tried using:
`$productcolor = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('leveranciersnummer');`, but that didn't work either. That doesn't even display NULL, that just leaves me with nothing.

In the backoffice, I tried setting 'Zichtbaar op productpagina's op frontend' to Yes too, and reindexed. But that neither did work.

Can somebody please point me into the right direction?
Am I forgetting something very simple?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if you are loading the configurable product or the simple product with $_item->getProduct() ? Also, i dont remember, if it's an order confimation Email Magento should take the items from the table: sales_flat_order_items, in that case you should do something like: $_item->getProductId() and load from there Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getLeveranciersnummer() or getData('leveranciersnummer'), and since sales_flat_order_items contains configurable and simple product you can try to check the product type too

Comment: Thanks. I've tried checking what type of product I'm loading, and it returns simple product. Then I tried this:
`$leverancier = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getLeveranciersnummer();` but that doesn't display anything. Can you help again maybe?

Comment: I also tried with getData('x'), but that also results in nothing, just blank space.
`$leverancier = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getData('leveranciersnummer');`

Comment: Unfortunatly i cannot test it, anyway digging on the Magento code i found this:                 Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getOrderItem()->getProductId())->getData('leveranciersnummer'); you can try with that

Comment: Hmm, still can't get it to work. Many, many thanks so far though!